# Possible to show the animation of scrolling on Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have seen posts on using the sleep function before scrolling to the element but I was wondering if its possible to actually show the process of scrolling, instead of hard cutting down to the element. I want the python script to scroll as if were using a mouse to scroll through a page.
So far I have the scroll line:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
```

which works, but just hard cuts down the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a lot simple than I thought.

```
from selenium import webdriver

path = 'D:\coding\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get('https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage') #ANY WEBSITE INSIDE BRACKETS

for i in range(1000):
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1)")
```

This seems to work perfectly, the only downside being that you cannot specify the length of time scrolling, only adjust the pixels.

Comment: I was using the console on inspect element, and was testing the position I want the browser to scroll to, lets say for example I chose to scroll to `window.scrollBy(300)`, and I chose the for loop to be `for i in range(300)`, and each loop, it scrolls down 1 pixel. However, when I run the loop, it comes out shorter than the expected destination. Is there a reason for this ?